# Trying to create stackable containers with image & text boxes next each 50/50 100%Width?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, grid

Here's what Im trying to accomplish, below this is what I have in code so far...

STEP 1: Trying to create two equal size boxes. One with text and a square image.

STEP 2: I need them to be side by side to span the full width of the page, yet stack when on a phone.

STEP 3: I need there containers to be stackable, I can repeat the process

STEP 3: Finally, I need the text box to always be on top of image box regarless of which order they are in their container.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0; 
  position: relative;
  color: #F0F0F0;
}

body{
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

.box_image{
    position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}    

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="Grant_box">  

<!--Set 1-->
    <div>
        <div class="box_image">
            <img src="text_box 1" style="width:100%">
            <div class="centered">Centered</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_image">
            <img src="Image_box 1" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>  
    
<!--Set 2-->
    <div>
        <div class="box_image">
            <img src="text_box 2" style="width:100%">
            <div class="centered">Centered</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_image">
            <img src="Image_box 2" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div> 
    
<!--Set 3-->
    <div>
        <div class="box_image">
            <img src="text_box 3" style="width:100%">
            <div class="centered">Centered</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_image">
            <img src="Image_box 3" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>    
    
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: css grid or flexboxes are your friend and then use media queries to change the layout.

Comment: yeah, I figured just not experienced enough to achieve it.

Comment: alright, I gave you short intro into CSS-Grid and emdia queries as anwser. However, please note that SO is not a tutorial nor a forum. Its for very specific coding issues. SO users aswell as guideliens require a minimal basic HTML and CSS understanding aswell as own research efford. CSS-Grid and flexboxes are nowadays a very basic thing and the 2 ways for mdoern web design.  So please do some research efford on those topics on your own.

Comment: That's fair, I just have a lot of stuff to do besides this. Forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with flexboxes. But personally I like to use css-grid for such task. You declare the column amount. By media queries is set, that at 480px or below, only 1 column is used and because of text-template-areas, that the text will be on top. Above 480px, 2 columns will be used and the position depending on the HTML structure.

Now you can simply add an image and push it into the image box and have the wanted column design.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content_box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    .content_box {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      grid-template-areas:
        "textBox"
        "imageBox";
    }
    
    .text_box {
      grid-area: textBox;
    }

    .image_box {
      grid-area: imageBox;
    }
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    .content_box {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);      
    }
}

/* for demostration only */

.content_box div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_box">
  <div class="image_box"></div>
  <div class="text_box">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this was extremely helpful!  Only thing is the photo and text boxes don't transition to full screen and stacked once screen width is reduced. It would be hard to read the text I presume at that size.

Comment: it will adept to the full width of the screen by default. If the screen resized so will the boxes. The .content_box has not width attribute which means by default the width will be auto (100% of the parents width). SO screen size or resizing shouldnt matter. If it doesnt resize, then you have css lines added that prevents them from doing it.

Comment: hummm. Makes sense.